# What means this TCP socket Error?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP socket sender and received this error

*Unable to read data from the transport connection: An error occurred during the connection attempt because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or there was an error in the connection established because connected host has failed to respond.*

The part that I don't understand is

*Unable to read data from the transport connection:*

Comment: That error message means a socket operation reported a `WSAETIMEDOUT` (10060) error. It would help if you would show the actual code where the error is being reported from.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The code that I have is from de TCP socket sender, the receiver(Server) is remote an designed by another company, so, I don't have that one. Did it help if I post my code? Can be an overflow on the receiver, cause the receiver is being debugged at this time, so, maybe, they put a breakpoint on their code. Can be that?

Comment: Yes, it would help to see your code, and please indicate the exact line of code that is failing. Yes, if the receiver is blocked, it can cause timeouts in your sender. But that implies that your sender is using timeouts to begin with. Are you really?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I shortened the timeout on purpose to about 15 seconds. I have no line, I'm not debugging my program the other company are. I'm just curious because I never saw that error before